# Terminate anonymous pipe when "output" process exits

Tags: shell-script, shell, process, pipe

So let's say I have something like this in a shell script

`command1 | command2`

Now how can I make it so that `command2` terminates when `command1` exits?

**Edit:**

> That usually happens by default when `command2` tries to read from standard input and notices that it returns 0. Do you have some concrete example where it doesn't do that?

Here you go: `echo test | xmobar`

And I guess this could be used as a substitute for `xmobar` as well

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
while :; do :; done
```

Comment: That will happen automatically. When command1 exits, the pipe closes and this tells command 2 it's not getting any more input.

Comment: That usually happens by default when `command2` tries to read from standard input and notices that it returns 0.  Do you have some concrete example where it doesn't do that?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to pipe input into a process that doesn't read from standard input (e.g., your script).  Does `xmobar` read from standard input?

Comment: It definitely does, the substitute I provided is purely for testing purposes

Comment: @HackSaw That's not strictly true. Closing the pipe in cmd1  does not tell cmd 2 anything at all. Nothing happens until cmd2 reads the pipe, empties it, and gets an EOF. Even then, it does not have to exit if it has work still to do. Similarly, if cmd2 exits first, cmd1 does not find out about it until it writes to the pipe, at which point it receives SIGPIPE. If it traps that, it too can carry on with other work.

Comment: Concrete example: In particular, for a construct like `find ... | xargs ...` or `myCmd | grep -f - ...` or `myCmd | sort > foo`, the main event doesn't even _start_ until the pipe has been read to EOF.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Given your name, is it ironic to point out that I didn't say that command1 closed the pipe? Nor did I say anything about what command2 had to do?

Comment: @HackSaw Even more pedantically, the pipe has a pair of descriptors, and the write descriptor is released when cmd1 exits. The pipe remains _open_ because there is an active read descriptor, and it stays open until cmd2 explicitly closes it, or cmd2 terminates. Even the EOF does not close the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/597287/108618#comment1115025_597287) explains how programs terminate (or not) when the other end of the pipe gets closed:

> Closing the pipe in `command1` does not tell `command2` anything at all. Nothing happens until `command2` reads the pipe, empties it, and gets an EOF. Even then, it does not have to exit if it has work still to do. Similarly, if `command2` exits first, `command1` does not find out about it until it writes to the pipe, at which point it receives `SIGPIPE`. If it traps that, it too can carry on with other work.

So this is what can happen automatically. Now your question:

> ```
> command1 | command2
> ```
>
> How can I make it so that `command2` terminates when `command1` exits [even if `command2` doesn't notice or doesn't want to terminate]?

If your shell runs the pipeline in a separate process group, try to kill the entire group. E.g. Bash does this when job control is enabled (`set -m`). It is enabled by default for interactive shells (on systems that support it), but not in scripts.

Example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
( command1; kill -s INT 0 ) | command2
```

The entire pipeline is run in a separate process group with PGID (process group ID) equal to the PID of the very first part, which in this case is a subshell. `kill 0` sends a signal to its own process group. This way we signal `command2` just after `command1` terminates.

Notes:

- In Bash `kill` is a builtin, so `kill` in the example is not a separate process with PID and PGID assigned. Therefore the phrase "its own process group" above is not strict, it should be "the process group of the subshell". It's still the exact process group we want to use. The `kill` builtin or `/bin/kill` can be used, any will work.
- `command2` may change its own process group. If it does, the solution will not work.
- For almost all signals `command2` may ignore the signal or handle it in virtually any way. Choose a signal that fits your needs.
- Calling `kill` just after `command1` terminates may be too soon. It may cause `command2` to exit before it reads and handles all the data generated by `command1`; and you may want it to handle all the data. Depending on how `command2` behaves, it may be useful to delay `kill` (e.g. `sleep 2; kill …`). Note that (general purpose) Linux is not a [real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), so any fixed delay may turn out to be too short if the circumstances are bad enough.